# Исключение при возвращении значения из поля класса

Tags: c++, qt

Ошибка: В отладчике возникла ошибка: Exception at 0x7ff701e0f9ca, code: 0xc0000005: read access violation at: 0x30, flags=0x0 (first chance)
По неизвестной мне причине возникает ошибка доступа к чтению полей в методе-геттере.
Геттер вызывается в ф-ии Ratio(), которая описана ниже. Место вызова метода класса обозначено в комментарии кода.

```
int DataPerson::GetAge() {
        return Age_;
    }
```

Вот ниже кусок кода, в котором возникает ошибка

```
ResultRat Ratio(vector<DataPerson> Vector, DataParametrs par, string EndDate) {
    string token;
    istringstream iss(par.Date);
    int j = 0;
    int DDay, DMonth, DYear;
    int DDay1, DMonth1, DYear1;
    while (getline(iss, token, '.')) {
        if (j == 0) DDay = atoi(token.c_str());
        if (j == 1) DMonth = atoi(token.c_str());
        if (j == 2) DYear = atoi(token.c_str());
        ++j;
    }
    istringstream iss1(EndDate);
    j = 0;
    while (getline(iss1, token, '.')) { //верхняя граница
        if (j == 0) DDay1 = atoi(token.c_str());
        if (j == 1) DMonth1 = atoi(token.c_str());
        if (j == 2) DYear1 = atoi(token.c_str());
        ++j;
    }
    if (DYear == DYear1) {//год
        if (DMonth == DMonth1) {//год и месяц
            if (DDay == DDay1) { // год месяц день
                // Вычислить процентное отношение полей из par относительно всех полей объектов из вектора
                int coutAge = 0;
                int coutRep = 0, coutDate = 0, coutType = 0;
                int coutMonth = 0;
                int coutYear=0;
                int coutNum = 0;
                int coutBP = 0;
                for (j = 0; j < Vector.size(); ++j) {
                    if (Vector[j].GetAge() == par.Age) coutAge++; //ОШИБКА ЗДЕСЬ ПРИ ВЫЗОВЕ Get.Age()
                    if (Vector[j].GetBP() == par.BP) coutBP++;
                    //if (Vector[j].GetMonth == par.Month) coutMonth++;
                    if (Vector[j].GetNum() == par.Num) coutNum++;
                    if (Vector[j].GetRep() == par.Rep) coutRep++;
                    if (Vector[j].GetType() == par.Type) coutType++;
                }

                ResultRat res(((double)coutRep / (double)Vector.size()), ((double)coutAge / (double)Vector.size()),
                    ((double)coutNum / (double)Vector.size()),((double)coutBP / (double)Vector.size()), ((double)coutType / (double)Vector.size())); //корявое приведение типа
                return res;
            }
            else { //если месяц и год один и тот же //
                string token2;
                int coutAge = 0;
                int coutRep = 0, coutDate = 0, coutType = 0;
                int coutMonth = 0;
                int coutYear = 0;
                int coutNum = 0;
                int coutBP = 0;
                for (j = 0; j < Vector.size(); ++j) {

                    istringstream iss2(Vector[j].GetDate());
                    int k = 0;
                    int DDay2, DMonth2, DYear2;
                    while (getline(iss2, token, '.')) {
                        if (k == 0) DDay2 = atoi(token.c_str());
                        if (k == 1) DMonth2 = atoi(token.c_str());
                        if (k == 2) DYear2 = atoi(token.c_str());
                        ++k;
                    }
                    if (DDay2 <= DDay1 && DDay2 >= DDay) {
                        if (Vector[j].GetAge() == par.Age) coutAge++;
                        if (Vector[j].GetBP() == par.BP) coutBP++;
                        //if (Vector[j].GetMonth == par.Month) coutMonth++;
                        if (Vector[j].GetNum() == par.Num) coutNum++;
                        if (Vector[j].GetRep() == par.Rep) coutRep++;
                        if (Vector[j].GetType() == par.Type) coutType++;
                    }
                }
                ResultRat res(((double)coutRep / (double)Vector.size()), ((double)coutAge / (double)Vector.size()),
                    ((double)coutNum / (double)Vector.size()), ((double)coutBP / (double)Vector.size()), ((double)coutType / (double)Vector.size())); //корявое приведение типа
                return res;

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Определение всего класса:

```
struct DataPerson
{
public:
    DataPerson(size_t N = 0, string Rep = "No data", int Age = 0, string Date = "No data", string Month = 0,
        int Year = 0, int Num = 0, int BP = 0, string Type = "No data");
    DataPerson(const DataPerson & copy);
    DataPerson& operator = (DataPerson& Obj);

    ~DataPerson();

    string GetDate();
    string GetRep();
    string GetType();
    size_t GetN();
    int GetAge();
    string GetMonth();
    int GetYear();
    int GetNum();
    int GetBP();

private:
    size_t N_;
    string Rep_;
    int Age_;
    string Date_;
    string Month_;
    int Year_;
    int Num_;
    int BP_;
    string Type_;
};
// DataPerson methods

    DataPerson::DataPerson(size_t N, string Rep, int Age, string Date, string Month,
        int Year, int Num, int BP, string Type)
        : N_(N), Age_(Age), Month_(Month), Year_(Year), Num_(Num), BP_(BP)
    {
        Date_ = Date;
        Rep_ = Rep;
        Type_ = Type;


    }
    DataPerson::DataPerson(const DataPerson & copy) : N_(copy.N_), Age_(copy.Age_), Month_(copy.Month_),
        Year_(copy.Year_), Num_(copy.Num_), BP_(copy.BP_), Date_(copy.Date_), Rep_(copy.Rep_), Type_(copy.Type_) {}

    DataPerson& DataPerson::operator = (DataPerson& Obj) {
        N_ = Obj.N_;
        Age_ = Obj.Age_;
        Month_ = Obj.Month_;
        Year_ = Obj.Year_;
        Num_ = Obj.Num_;
        BP_ = Obj.BP_;
        Date_ = Obj.Date_;
        Rep_ = Obj.Rep_;
        Type_ = Obj.Type_;
        return *this;
    }

    DataPerson::~DataPerson() {

    }
    string DataPerson::GetDate() {
        return Date_;
    }
    string DataPerson::GetRep() {
        return Rep_;
    }
    string DataPerson::GetType() {
        return Type_;
    }
    size_t DataPerson::GetN() {
        return N_;
    }
    int DataPerson::GetAge() {
        return Age_;
    }
    string DataPerson::GetMonth() {
        return Month_;
    }
    int DataPerson::GetYear() {
        return Year_;
    }
    int DataPerson::GetNum() {
        return Num_;
    }
    int DataPerson::GetBP() {
        return BP_;
    }

    // End of DataPerson methods
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код работал без исключений в VS. Запустил в Qt и выкидывает ошибку.

Comment: Кода слишком много, определите строчку возникновения ошибки -- хоть под отладчиком, хоть проставив в коде отладочные сообщения в консоль

Comment: @gil9red скриншота и комментария в коде недостаточно? Мне кажется, что строка возникновения ошибки чётко видна, ведь на скриншоте стоит точка останова на 53 строке с сообщением ошибки.

Comment: Если я неверно понял замечание, поправьте меня и скажите, пожалуйста, точнее указания к оформлению проблемы

Comment: Скриншот в таких проблема лучше указывать дополнительно, а не как основная проблема -- сам текст ошибки должен быть в вопросе и на это есть несколько причин: возможность скопировать его для поиска и для поиска самого вопроса по ошибке -- т.к. большинство попадают на сайт из поисковых систем

Comment: @gil9red Сейчас внесу справку, спасибо

Comment: Типичная попытка доступа через null-указатель.

Comment: @AnT в чём она заключается и как это исправить?

Comment: Откройте stacktrace и смотрите откуда идет вызов GetAge. Внутри GetAge this уже ноль, но непонятно почему, поэтому нужно ловить ноль до вызова. Трассируйте. Вариант2 - Если среда позволяет скипнуть код до возврата - скипните одну строчку в трассировке (не все отладчики так умеют) - тогда сразу увидите кто вызвал без стактрейса.